# Related Work to Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I am writing my end term report on Mathematica. Can anyone explain or point me to a website/article on "Related Work" to Mathematica? I am asking in this forum because i can find that information nowhere. 
Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "related work" mean?

Comment: good place for this, http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/ though id recomend being more clear about what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:  http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/

In the section for each type of industry there are videos from professional users.

E.g. Under 'Aerospace' there are videos from Boeing and INRIA.